# Attach lldb/gdb to a short-lived process?

Tags: gdb, lldb

I am debugging a program that is short-lived. That is, it won't stop and wait for the lldb/gdb debugger to attach. So how can I attach lldb debugger to this kind of process?

Comment: Get the debugger to start the process? Change the code to add a sleep at the start?

Comment: Have some way to test that program independently, and start it inside `gdb`

Comment: http://tromey.com/blog/?p=734 ?

Comment: @EdHeal I am using vim-lldb as a lldb frontend, so it is not possible to start it in the debugger. And I don't think hacking into the code is a good idea :)

Comment: One would imagine that you have access to the source code (hence doing the debugging). Just put after main a sleep for ten seconds . Give you time to attach the debugger

Comment: @John - if you are using `vim-lldb`, why did you label the question with GDB? And why did you mention it in a comment, and not the question?

Comment: @jww Because gdb does not work just like lldb. And I am not sure. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional approach is to have a sleep loop, or if you have access to the source, to put a busyloop like

```
int wait_for_debugger = 1
while (wait_for_debugger)
    ;
```

Then you attach to the process and set `wait_for_debugger` to 0 (e.g. `p wait_for_debugger = 0`) and continue the process.

lldb has a `--waitfor` option to attach to a process.  This has lldb repeatedly poll the process table looking for a new instance of that process name and attaches to it.  The process will get to execute a little bit but the polling frequency is high enough that it usually catches things early enough.  This is the `process launch --waitfor --name procname` command, or `pr la -w -n processname` for short.

Answer (score 1):

> So how can I attach lldb debugger to this kind of process?

Attach the debugger to the parent process, and `set follow-fork-mode child`. According to the docs, *"The new process is debugged after a fork. The parent process runs unimpeded"*. See [4.11 Debugging Forks](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Forks.html) in the GDB manual.